# dask: distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize

Tags: dask

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
...
df = dd.read_csv('*.csv')
```

versions:
dask                      2.15.0                     py_0
dask-core                 2.15.0                     py_0
geopandas                 0.6.1                      py_0
pandas                    1.0.3            py37h47e9c7a_0
pandas-datareader         0.8.1                    pypi_0
pyarrow                   0.15.1           py37h47e9c7a_0

I noticed bug report #2597 on:

https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2597

it was closed on sep 2019, Was it resolved since then?

Comment: That problem seems to have been a user issue --  `usecols must be list-like` .

Comment: indeed, typecasting the argument as list solved the problem, thank you

Answer (score 1):

That problem seems to have been a user issue -- `usecols must be list-like`